# Is there any way in python to parse files in a directory full of directories full of text files to find for a match?

Tags: python, directory, txt

I have a directory full of other directories with thousands of text files and I don't know how to parse every file to look for matches. Is there any way in python?

I tried the read file module but I have to specify a directory and I don't know how to open every file, not only the ones I specified.

Comment: Step 1: list all the files. Step 2: open each file and look for whatever you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a character that separates each directory, you can use that to split the text.

Search about the split function in Python.

' txt.split('') '

If you put the text it's more easy to explain.